# Measure returning a blank value, should pick up the data from latest available previous value

Tags: dax

I have a matrix by Fiscal year and Fiscal Month, where i have added a measure to show a starting HC by Fiscal year wise.

I want all the Fiscal year months to show the HC to be same as Fiscal Year Starting HC. e'.g, Our FY starts from Aug, So in that particular FY all the months should show Aug HC.

So is there using DAX can we pull the previous available non blank value from a measure and fill the blank values.

[Here is my Current Output and Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXvO2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGYca.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to show the same value for the entire fiscal year based on all the values in that year?

```
HC_FY = 
VAR _SelectedYear = MAX(DIM_DATE[FY])
RETURN
Calculate(SUM(HC_SALES), DIM_DATE[FY] = _SelectedYear)
```

By doing this you will retrieve the selected year for each date within the year and sum the HC sales for that entire Fiscal Year. This way it doesn't matter what month/ date is selected.